# DelegatingHandler Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, dotnet-httpclient

I have a class `AuthorizationHandler` that is derived from `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`. It has a DI constuctor and overrides the `SendAsync` method to retrieve an authorization token from `AuthenticationService` before every request.

```
public class AuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _service;
    public AuthorizationHandler(IAuthenticationService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", await _service.GetAccessToken());
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

However I receive the following DI registration issue whenever `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient()` is invoked:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'MyProject.AuthenticationService.AuthorizationHandler' has been registered.

The following is a relevant snippet of my Autofac configuration.

```
...    
// Creates an IoC container and registers infrastructure modules 
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
...
containerBuilder.RegisterType<AuthorizationHandler>().InstancePerDependency();
// ALSO TRIED
// containerBuilder.RegisterType<AuthorizationHandler>().As<DelegatingHandler>().InstancePerDependency();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<AuthenticationService>().As<IAuthenticationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
containerBuilder.Register<IHttpClientFactory>(_ =>
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/authenticate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-api-key",
                "MY-API-KEY");
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizationHandler>();
        // ALSO TRIED
        // .AddHttpMessageHandler((provider) => provider.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationHandler>());
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    return provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
}).SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Since you have a reference to `services`, can't you call `services.AddTransient<AuthorizationHandler>();`  before `AddHttpClient`?

Comment: So this *kind of* works. When adding `services.AddTransient<AuthorizationHandler>();` before `AddHttpClient`, it successfully registers the `AuthorizationHandler` for usage as a message handler. However, it seems that this creates a sort of dependency scope and now any class that instantiate a HttpClient through `clientFactory.CreateClient()` also needs **their** dependencies registered inside the `IHttpClientFactory` definition as well (ie services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>()). Ideally, I would like to register all dependencies just once outside of this scope

Answer (score 3):

It appears [you fell victim to one of the classic blunders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMz7JBRbmNo). The most famous is never get involved in a land war in Asia. But only slightly less well known is this: **You can't mix-and-match Autofac registrations with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection registrations.**

I mean, I get it, it would not be awesome to have to replicate some of that `.AddHttpClient` stuff. But I also see in the sample snippet this:

```cs
containerBuilder.Register<IHttpClientFactory>(_ =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient("MyApi", client =>
```

Which means this is a closure over `services`, which gets... temporarily built? and then still ends up contributing to a different container (Autofac), which will then back the DI for the rest of the calls?

Based on the snippet I have to assume you've [integrated Autofac as the backing DI container](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) and, as part of that, are using [the `AutofacServiceProviderFactory`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacServiceProviderFactory.cs) at app startup (as noted in the docs). If you're not doing that, and/or not following the docs, then the rest of the container setup - how you're actually building it, where `services` gets created, etc. - is all pretty relevant to the issue at hand and is not part of the question/repro. (That's why [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so important. What's here is not reproducible and is a step past minimal.)

Making the assumption that you're setting things up in a sort of supported way, the general order of operations in a standard ASP.NET Core app is:

1. Create `IServiceCollection services`.
2. Call `ConfigureServices(services)` to get registrations into the Microsoft format.
3. Call the `AutofacServiceProviderFactory` to get a `ContainerBuilder`. This will...

   1. Create a `ContainerBuilder`.
   2. Convert the Microsoft format registrations into Autofac registrations and put those in the `ContainerBuilder`. ([`builder.Populate(services)`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/c715e5f6c82f6481c299411fd0ec1f746f5f6aa5/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacRegistration.cs#L26))
   3. Return that `ContainerBuilder` with all the Microsoft registrations already in it.
4. Call `ConfigureContainer(builder)` with that `ContainerBuilder`.
5. Hand that `ContainerBuilder` back to `AutofacServiceProviderFactory` to...

   1. Create the container - `builder.Build()`.
   2. Wrap that in an `IServiceProvider` interface.

So if you have interesting/odd stuff like "mix and match Microsoft registrations inside a delegate that you're registering in Autofac," you're going to get really painful-to-troubleshoot problems like you're describing now. You're kind of working with two different containers, right? You have

- The Autofac one, which is built from the set of `services` *before* `ConfigureContainer` ran along with the stuff from `ConfigureContainer`; AND
- An odd "partial container" that is being accessed from inside an Autofac registration delegate, which has the stuff from `ConfigureServices` and the stuff from inside the delegate, but is not the same as the set of registrations being used to back the rest of the application.

**Don't mix and match.** Unwind all that and do not register new services or make tiny temporary containers inside delegates.

I can't promise this will fix the problem, but it will probably make it *far, far easier* to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly detailed answer Travis (and that welcomed Princess Bride ref). I admittedly made another blunder and forgot to add my `service` initialization in my code, which I have done so. It's done within the scope of registering `IHttpClientFactory` and is scoped to that single block. This particular container is one of many other modules, which is based on this [modular monolith architecture](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd).

Comment: I can't speak to the modular monolith architecture, but again, I think... you may not be getting straightforward results if you're mixing and matching, even if it's building its own tiny container in there. That's going to be limited to what you registered in that tiny container and it looks like that will need the handler that's having trouble. I would strongly urge you to split that out. Register MS stuff in one spot, register Autofac stuff in a different spot, let the system combine the two. Multi-container is _problems_.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801603/obtaining-a-scoped-service-in-a-custom-delegating-handler-in-blazor-server) may be really usefull for you. Problem seems to be very similar.

Quote from the accepted answer:

> dependency injection manages the http request pipeline scopes completely separately from the http clients themselves, there's no reliable way to ensure that the pipeline has the same scope as the request

And the problem is that your *IAuthenticationService* is registered as scoped.

In-depth explanation of the problem can be found here, [in the blog post by Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net/understanding-scopes-with-ihttpclientfactory-message-handlers/#an-example-of-unexpected-for-me-scoped-service-behaviour-in-ihttpclientfactory).

Solution to your problem may be resolve *IAuthenticationService* from *IHttpContextAccessor*. I am not sure how it should be done with Autofac, but with built-in DI it would look like:

```
public class AuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public AuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var service = _accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>();

        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", await service.GetAccessToken());
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking this is the solution here, but I am indeed having some Autofac issues. Specifically a `Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException` where the runtime is claiming `IAbsorbAuthenticationService` has not been registered. This is despite having it registered as typed above in my `containerBuilder` :/

Comment: I would do the following before blaming Autofac: try to register IAuthenticationService as transient or singleton and see if there is any difference. Or even better, add some fake/test dependency registered as transient or singleton and inject it to your delegating handler instead of authentication service and see if there is any difference. Does it work? I assume that IAuthenticationService has to be scoped, so just try with some really dummy dependency.

Comment: Attempted to inject a dummy class `DummyService` through `IDummyService` and registered the component as both `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and `SingleInstance` to no avail. `GetRequiredService` throws that the component `IDummyService` is not registered.